# What's the difference between function attributes and variables in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, attributes

I'm trying to create a self-contained counter function, but if I use a variable it resets each time the function is called, but it works when I use function.attribute.

```
def turncounter():
    try:
        turns = turns + 1
    except:
        turns = 0
    try:
        turncounter.turn = turncounter.turn + 1
    except:
        turncounter.turn = 0
    print(turns,turncounter.turn)
turncounter()
turncounter()
```

It returns:

```
0 0
0 1
```

Why is that?
Aren't function variables and function attributes the same?
And is it correct to use function.attribute instead of using variables?

Comment: _"Aren't function variables and function attributes the same?"_ - no, as your example demonstrates. _"is it correct to use function.attribute instead of using variables?"_ - it depends on the behaviour you want.

Comment: Attributes are associated with the object to which they're attached, in this case your function.  Since you only have one instance of the function, you only have one instance of each of its attributes.  Local variables, on the other hand, are associated with a specific invocation of a function.  Each time a function is called, a new invocation is created.  Otherwise things like recursion wouldn't work.

Comment: Local variables in a function are thought to be `"on the stack"` which is re-created every time the function is entered. Function attributes are just attributes and functions are just objects to which attributes can be attached, just like classes and class variables.

Comment: why not create a variable outside the function and then pass that variable into the function and then return the result. Set that variable to the returned result

Comment: The normal way to do this is to create a class that holds your state information.  Then make the function a method of the class.

Comment: Another option is to make `turncounter` a generator function. You advance the counter by calling `next` on it, or simply iterating over it. (Your function, call to `print` aside, is basically the same as `itertools.count`.)

Comment: Note that you can also initialize `turncounter.turn = 0`, without the try except, in the main scope, after the function definition.  Think of the function as an object (it is) which you can now stick the variable onto for permanency.  The function body’s local scope however resets as a blank slate every time.